# Stop Docker from automatically starting on startup

Tags: startup, docker

I installed Docker on OS X, and now it automatically loads every time I log in. Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Click the Docker icon in the right hand side of the menu bar, and click "Preferences". In the dialog that appears, untick "Automatically start Docker when you log in".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you know what's causing it to run? It's not one of the Login Items (in System Preferences).

Comment: @mjs It's a [`launchd` service](http://www.launchd.info/). You'll see two Docker services when running `launchctl list | grep docker`.

Comment: Do you know where its plist is stored? Can't find it on my system.

Comment: I had both 'Docker' And 'Docker Desktop' installed. I had to open the one called 'Docker' and then click the cog-wheel symbol, in the top right. There was no 'Preferences' if I clicked  on 'Docker' in the top bar.

Comment: None of these solutions work for me.  The option under "Preferences" is definitely not checked, and I've done a `launchctl remove` on both the entries, but after a reboot it comes back!

Comment: It looks like disabling "checking for updates" is only available on paid plans now: "Paid Team plans allow IT-managed organizations to disable checking for updates."

Answer (score 15):

The locations are

```bsh
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cd ~/Library/LaunchDaemons

cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cd ~/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

But I recommend you just remove using `launchctl remove`

```bsh
launchctl list | grep docker

launchctl remove com.docker.helper
launchctl remove com.docker.docker.11008
```

Comment: I think this is a better approach, because I also have other application having the same issue. and I don't need to go to each application to remove them from launch. I was able to remove my another application by removing it in LaunchAgents but I can't do it with launchctl remove though, they will still launch on startup after i restart my laptop